# How to line break in WhatsApp with Selenium when sending a message?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, whatsapp

Message sending function:

```py
template = {
    'other': 
             'Text.'
             'More Text.'
             'Much more text.'
}


def send_message(driver, answer):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('XPATH').click()
    action = ActionChains(driver)
    action.send_keys(answer)
    action.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    action.perform()
```

Depending on the received message from the `template`, the necessary answer is taken and passed to `send_message()` as the `answer` argument.
If you send the message as is, then in WhatsApp it comes in one line:

`Text.More text.Much more text.`

If you add `\n` then each line will be sent with a new message, i.e. like that:

[screenshot of sent message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mA9k.jpg)

How can I send text with line breaks in one message?

Comment: @JeffC bcs I found a solution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved this

```py
def send_message(driver, answer):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('XPATH').click()
    for line in answer.split('\n'):
        ActionChains(driver).send_keys(line).perform()
        ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.SHIFT).key_down(Keys.ENTER).key_up(Keys.SHIFT).key_up(Keys.ENTER).perform()
    ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.RETURN).perform()
```

Comment: Thanks for the osam answer. Save my day.

Comment: this works, but for my multi line (say 100+) comment, the time taken to create the message is considerable. As it is an activity done in DOM. Can it be sped up? Like pasting just one time would be perfect

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to add the line. It is working fine and I am using it in my ERP.

```
smsContain = "*Greetings from  " + cname + " ,%0a %0a M/s. " + txtName.Text + " %0a %0a
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Basically pressing `SHIFT+ENTER` every time a new line appears.

```py
MESSAGE = """This is a sample message.
It accepts one new line.


also accepts multiple new lines as well.
"""

for one_line in MESSAGE.split("\n"):
    driver.find_element('').send_keys(one_line)
    driver.find_element('').send_keys(Keys.SHIFT + Keys.ENTER)
driver.find_element('').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Answer (score 0):

I try with

"\n" or (Keys.Shift + Keys.Enter) or Environment.NewLine

to make  multiple lines in WhatsApp Group using Selenium With C# but not work

I use Alt and it's work to send message with multiple lines on Whatsapp Group

(Keys.Alt + Keys.Enter)